# What configuration can insert lines between commands?

Tags: bash

I've noticed on some Linux servers, that bash has a very elegant feature that adds visual breaks.

What program is it that appends the `-------- <time>` after each command?

[image]

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5840450/add-a-handy-separator-between-commands-in-your-terminal-on-mac-os-x-and-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is a modified `PS1` environment variable.

`PS1` is a variable that defines the behavior of the default interactive prompt. By default `PS1` is set to something like `\u@\h \w`, where:

- `\u` is the username
- `\h` is the hostname
- and `\w` is the working directory.

To set up a new `PS1` environment variable you can always `export PS1="<the_new_PS1>"` or you may set one at either `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`.

In the picture you have linked to, `PS1` is set to:

```
\[\033[00m\]\[\033[0;37m\]$fill \t\n\[\033[00m\]${debian_chroot:+$(debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

[@choroba](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/13792/choroba) has also done a very good job with [providing you with a guide](http://lifehacker.com/5840450/add-a-handy-separator-between-commands-in-your-terminal-on-mac-os-x-and-linux) to help you set up your `PS1` variable to have the same effect

If you would like to read more about `PS1` [you can do so here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-take-control-of-ps1-ps2-ps3-ps4-and-prompt_command/). You can also look at various examples on how you could possibly set up `PS1` [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/bash-shell-ps1-10-examples-to-make-your-linux-prompt-like-angelina-jolie/)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that with:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "%*s" $((COLUMNS-9)) " "|sed "s/./-/g"; date "+ %T"'
PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

The `PROMPT_COMMAND` executes whenever bash is about to display a prompt.

Comment: Your solution was simple enough and it worked for me. +1

Comment: With newer `bash` versions: `printf '%*(-%T)T' "$COLUMNS" -1 | tr ' -' '- '`

Comment: Can you use this technique to print time statements between each line of a bash script?

Comment: No, a non-interactive script does not have a prompt. You'd have to program that yourself.